# ScrollBarVisibility Hidden vs Disabled

Tags: .net, wpf

***What is the difference between `ScrollBarVisibility` `Hidden` & `Disabled`?***

I tried both and they render the `ScrollBar` with `Visibility` as `Collapse`. Can someone elaborate with an example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to MSDN][1],

- **Disabled**

  A ScrollBar does not appear even when the viewport cannot display all of the content. The dimension of the content is set to the corresponding dimension of the ScrollViewer parent. For a horizontal ScrollBar, the width of the content is set to the ViewportWidth of the ScrollViewer. For a vertical ScrollBar, the height of the content is set to the ViewportHeight of the ScrollViewer.
- **Hidden**

  A ScrollBar does not appear even when the viewport cannot display all of the content. **The dimension of the ScrollViewer is not applied to the content.**

Comment: Can you give any example ?

Comment: @KyloRen Added example

Comment: @KyloRen Thanks for the screenshot